# Python Mail Converts Random Characters to '='

Tags: python, encoding, webkit, gtk, imap

I am writing an email application using PyGTK. In almost every message that I am receiving from the server, random characters are replaced by '=' symbols. It's something to do with the character encoding, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to post an example along with some code.

Comment: You shouldn't prepend `ANSWERED`, also, post your solution as an answer to your own question :)

Comment: I'm a "new user", so I can't answer my own question for 8 hours. I didn't want anyone to waste their time on it given that I already knew the answer.

Comment: Ah, that is probably to stop new users who use the answer box to follow up other answers. If you think your answer could be helpful to others, post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When I run get_payload, I have to set decode to True.

```
for mailpart in mailitem.walk():
    if mailpart.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    message = str(mailpart.get_payload(decode=True))
```